# tailwind stopped working suddenly in react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Tailwind was working fine, I used this documentation to configure it (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) , then I wanted to add colors, so I edited tailwind.config.js file. But after that Tailwind stopped working, although I deleted tailwind.config.js and redo the steps of installation.
my  tailwind.config.js file:

```
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/*.{html,js}",
    "./public/*.{html,js}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import './main.css';
import App from './App';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

The commands I used:

```
     npx tailwindcss init

Created Tailwind CSS config file: tailwind.config.js  
PS C:\Users\****\OneDrive\Documents\Desktop\Good Quotes\goodquotes> npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/index.css --watch
>> 

Rebuilding...
Done in 214ms.
```

One of my components:

```
const TypesBar = ({handler}) =>{


    return(
    <nav className="flex bg-slate-800 sm:justify-center space-x-4">
    {[
      ['Philosophy'],
      ['Religion'],
      ['Love'],
      ['Despair']
    ].map((title) => (
      <button onClick={handler} value={title} className="rounded-lg px-3 py-2 text-slate-50 font-medium hover:bg-white hover:text-slate-900">{title}</button>
    ))}
  </nav>
    )
       

}
```

[Picture of the current state of the site:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSoIH.png)

Comment: am I seeing a typo in button ? space should be there before className

Comment: @Kaneki21 Its was working fine, its a typo but it doesn't effect the code. But I corrected it anyway

Comment: can you check the css for the classes in devtools elements, check if everything is coming or not

Comment: @Kaneki21 it seems to me that its coming, for example: https://imgur.com/G68nPmy

Comment: @Kaneki21 after a dozen of trail and error, deleting codes editing etc.. I discovered that if I copied the code component and applied it directly in the app.js , it works!, then if I undo that(I mean using the component again) it still works ! couldn't figure out why this is happening. do you have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use the CRA [Guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app) . Can have a try at that.